# Is there a pandas function to display the first/last n columns, as in .head() & .tail()?

Tags: python, pandas

I love using the `.head()` and `.tail()` functions in pandas to circumstantially display a certain amount of rows (sometimes I want less, sometimes I want more!).  But is there a way to do this with the columns of a DataFrame?

Yes, I know that I can change the display options, as in:
`pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 20)`

But that is too clunky to keep having to change on-the-fly, and anyway, it would only replace the `.head()` functionality, but not the `.tail()` functionality.

I also know that this could be done using an accessor:
`yourDF.iloc[:,:20]` to emulate .head(20) and `yourDF.iloc[:,-20:]` to emulate .tail(20).

It may look like a short amount of code, but honestly it's not as intuitive nor swift as when I use .head().

Does such a command exist? I couldn't find one!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No, such methods are not supplied by Pandas, but it is easy to make these methods yourself:

```
import pandas as pd
def front(self, n):
    return self.iloc[:, :n]

def back(self, n):
    return self.iloc[:, -n:]

pd.DataFrame.front = front
pd.DataFrame.back = back

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(4,10)))
```

So that now *all* DataFrame would possess these methods:

```
In [272]: df.front(4)
Out[272]: 
   0  1  2  3
0  2  5  2  8
1  9  9  1  3
2  7  0  7  4
3  8  3  9  2

In [273]: df.back(3)
Out[273]: 
   7  8  9
0  3  2  7
1  9  9  4
2  5  7  1
3  3  2  5

In [274]: df.front(4).back(2)
Out[274]: 
   2  3
0  2  8
1  1  3
2  7  4
3  9  2
```

---

If you put the code in a utility module, say, `utils_pandas.py`, then you can activate it with an import statement:

```
import utils_pandas
```

Comment: nice!  thanks, @unutbu!  I'm VERY new to python & pandas (& programming altogether!), so I still haven't wrapped my head around UDF's.  This will be a great first attempt.

Comment: i tried putting a script with the function definitions in a folder listed in my sys.path, opened a new (IPython) console, did `import pandas as pd`, and then `import utils_pandas`, but I it says :
    NameError: name 'pd' is not defined
Any idea why the module doesn't recognize my `pd` alias?

Comment: Every module has its own "global" namespace. So putting `import pandas as pd` in one module (or script or in the console) does not define `pd` in another module. So be sure to put `import pandas as pd` in `utils_pandas.py`.

Answer (score 2):

Closest emulation, which you could put in a function:

```
number_of_columns = 5 # eg.
head_cols = df[df.columns[:number_of_columns]]
tail_cols = df[df.columns[-number_of_columns:]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Transpose it to use head and go back

```
df.T.head().T
```

to avoid index slicing or custom methods.

Answer (score -1):

You could just use df.col.head(n) for what your are trying to do... see example below,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [i for i in range(101)],
                   'b': [i for i in range(101)]})
df.a.head(4)

Out[37]:
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

Comment: this is not what i am trying to do.  the maxymoo & unutbu answers demonstrate (& solve!) the problem very elegantly!

Answer (score -1):

You can just put a number inside brackets which will show n first/last number
of rows in your dataframe.

```
df.head(10)
```

*You can even put a lower number than the default (if you want too).*

```
df.head(2)
```

Comment: The user don't want the first n rows, but the first n columns.